# Interpretation of Non-significant Coefficients

Tags: regression, interpretation

My regression uses OLS and annual macroeconomics data. I find one independent variable (x), negative and not statistical significant.From the theory I expected to see (x) to be negative and statistical significant.

Is it appropriate to say: "there is no **any** link between x and y"? or

"the x has a negative sign but it is not statistical significant"? or

other

The first sentence does not give any chance to give some policy implications. However, the second could let me to talk a little bit for policy implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you test a hypothesis (any hypothesis), there is the possibility of both a Type I error (rejecting $H_0$ even though it is false) and a Type II error (not rejecting $H_0$ even though it is true).

In your case, you did not reject the null hypothesis (that the coefficient relating $x$ and $y$ is zero) , but you cannot (a priori) rule out the possibility of a Type II error. In other words, the coefficient still could be nonzero. The proper way to phrase that is to day that the link between $x$ and $y$ is not statistically significant (after all, your experiment *did* give you a nonzero estimate).

My preference would be to turn your second statement on its head: The relationship between $x$ and $y$ is not statistically significant, although the coefficient has the sign expected from the theory.